# Автоматическая передача данных их одной таблицы django в другую

Tags: python, django

подскажите, пожалуйста. Вот, к примеру, у меня есть такая модель:

```py
class Road_list(models.Model):
    data_start = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True, verbose_name='Дата выдачи')
    data_finall = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True, verbose_name='Действителен до')
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(Contragent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Выберите организацию инициатора')
    marka_auto = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Выберите тягач')
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Выберите водителя')
    trailer_type = models.ForeignKey(Trailer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Выберите прицеп')
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Dcotors, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Выберите сотрудника для медосмотра')
    mechanic = models.ForeignKey(staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Выберите механика')
    logist = models.ForeignKey(staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Выберите логиста', related_name='staff_logist')
```

и вот такая:

```
class Road_trts(models.Model):
    road_info = models.ForeignKey(Road_list,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Как я могу автоматически передать запись из Road_list в Road_trts? К примеру, я добавил новую запись в Road_list, и, после сохранения этой записи, эта запись так же попадает в Road_trts.

Comment: Через сигналы в модели на сохранение данных

Comment: @Павел, спасибо вам, я новичок в Django, но теперь я знаю куда копать =) пойду читать как работать с сигналами!